# Reverse Engineering: changing AL register without overwriting instructions

Tags: debugging, assembly, executable, reverse-engineering, x86-64

I am trying to learn more about reverse engineering by debugging and patching a 64 bit windows executable. I am using x64dbg (Much like ollydbg but with 64 bit support)

I have some assembly that looks roughly like this:

```
call test_exe.44AA9EB20
mov byte ptr ds:[44AB9DA15], al
[More instructions...]
[More instructions...]
[More instructions...]
```

the function call in the first line sets the rax register to have a value of 0. Therefore, the second line is moves a value of 0 into the pointer at 44AB9DA15.

I want to reassemble some code so that a value of 1 gets put into this pointer.

I can do something like this:

```
call test_exe.44AA9EB20
mov byte ptr ds:[44AB9DA15], 1
```

However, since al is only an 8 bit register, assembling the code to the above seems to run over some of the subsequent instructions.

I know that I can solve this problem by stepping into the function call test_exe.44AA9EB20 and setting rax to have a value of 1 before the ret instruction, but I am curious if there is an easier way.

**Is there some way I can give this pointer (44AB9DA15) a value of 1 without running over subsequent instructions?**

Comment: You should try posting this question in Reverse Engineering stack exchange site: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sometimes you have to look broader than just the single instruction and think about replacing a small block of a few instructions with a different set. So that said, can you show a few of the "More instructions..." that you mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to replace **MOV [0x000000044AB9DA15],AL**  which is encoded as 88042515DAB94A (7 bytes) 
with **MOV BYTE PTR [0x000000044AB9DA15],1**  which is encoded as C6042515DAB94A01 (one byte longer).
Try to use RIP-relative encoding. First calculate the difference between the target pointer and the offset 
of following instruction ($+instruction_size). If it is less than 2GB, for instance 0x11223344,
the encoding of **MOV BYTE PTR REL [0x000000044AB9DA15-$-7]** will be C6054433221101 (exactly 7 bytes).

Or, if **test_exe** doesn't have to be called, overwrite the CALL instruction with code which sets AL to 1,
e.g. **MOV AL,1**, and pad the remaining four bytes with **NOP**.